# How do i get buttons to correspond to different drop down divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div section that slides down when a button is clicked. However, I have three buttons which requires 3 different drop down divs. How do I get each button to drop down a div with different content?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maddiwu/xe6xtfqh/

```css
.slide {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-height: 100vw;
    /* approximate max height */
    width:100%;
    /*height: 45vw;*/
    background:#2e2e2e;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(1, 1, 1, 1);
}
.slide.closed {
    max-height: 0;
}
.banner7 {
    width:80%;
    background:#d8d8d8;
    margin-top:1.5vw;
    padding-top:2vw;
}
.banner8 {
    width:80%;
    background:#2e2e2e;
    margin-top:1vw;
    margin-left:10%;
    padding-top:2vw;
}
```

```html
<center>
    <div class="banner7" style="margin-bottom:0vw;margin-top:2vw;">
         <h1 style="color:#B40404;font-size:2.5vw;margin:1.5vw;font-family:Futura;">MAIN SECTION</h1>

        <p style="font-family:Helvetica Neue;font-size:1vw;color:back;margin-left:5vw; margin-right:5vw; text-align:center; margin-top:-1vw;margin-bottom:3vw;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
        <table style="width:95%; margin-left:2%;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div style="background:white;width:21vw;margin-top:0vw;margin-bottom:2vw;padding:1vw;">
                         <h1 style="color:#b40404;font-size:1.5vw;font-family:Futura; text-align:center;margin-top:1vw;">SUB SECTION ONE</h1>

                        <p style="font-family:Helvetica Neue;font-size:1vw;color:#2e2e2e; text-align:center; margin-top:1vw;margin-bottom:1vw;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
                        <center>
                            <img src="images/button.png" style="width:35%;height:3vw;margin-top:1vw; margin-bottom:1vw;" onmouseover="this.src='images/button-hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/button.png'" onload="closed" onclick="document.getElementById('slide').classList.toggle('closed');" />
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div style="background:white;width:21vw;margin-top:0vw;margin-bottom:2vw;padding:1vw;">
                         <h1 style="color:#b40404;font-size:1.5vw;font-family:Futura; text-align:center;margin-top:1vw;">SUB SECTION TWO</h1>

                        <p style="font-family:Helvetica Neue;font-size:1vw;color:#2e2e2e; text-align:center; margin-top:1vw;margin-bottom:1vw;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
                        <center>
                            <img src="images/button.png" style="width:35%;height:3vw;margin-top:1vw; margin-bottom:1vw;" onmouseover="this.src='images/button-hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/button.png'" onclick="document.getElementById('slide').classList.toggle('closed');" />
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div style="background:white;width:21vw;margin-top:0vw;margin-bottom:2vw;padding:1vw;">
                         <h1 style="color:#b40404;font-size:1.5vw;font-family:Futura; text-align:center;margin-top:1vw;">SUB SECTION THREE</h1>

                        <p style="font-family:Helvetica Neue;font-size:1vw;color:#2e2e2e; text-align:center; margin-top:1vw;margin-bottom:1vw;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.</p>
                        <center>
                            <img src="images/button.png" style="width:35%;height:3vw;margin-top:1vw; margin-bottom:1vw;" onmouseover="this.src='images/button-hover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/button.png'" onclick="document.getElementById('slide').classList.toggle('closed');" />
                        </center>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</center>
<div>
    <div class="slide" id="slide">
        <div style="width:100%; background:#2e2e2e; padding:1vw; text-align:center;">
            <table style="width:80%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <iframe style="margin-left:20%;width:45vw;height:30vw;" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/P7mS83pOPso" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <center>
                             <h1 style="color:#d8d8d8;font-size:2.5vw;font-family:Futura; text-align:center;margin-top:0vw;margin-left:20vw;">DROP SECTION</h1>

                            <p style="font-family:Helvetica Neue;font-size:1vw;color:white;margin-left:11vw;margin-right:-8vw; text-align:center; margin-top:1vw;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </center>
        </div>
        <div style="width:100%; background:#d8d8d8; padding:1vw; text-align:center;">
            <center>
                <center>
                     <h1 style="color:#b40404;font-size:2.5vw;font-family:Futura; text-align:center;margin-top:2vw;">DROP SECTION</h1>

                    <p style="font-family:Helvetica Neue;font-size:1vw;color:#2e2e2e;margin-right:10vw;margin-left:10vw; text-align:center; margin-top:-1vw;margin-bottom:2vw;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</p>
                </center>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<br>
```

Comment: your html is kind of messy can you reformat and post it again without having inline styles!

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with code because it will take to much time but i can give the idea.

You can use MVC(Model View Controller pattern) that will help you with rendering the data on single div.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the limitations of CSS, you can't change a style based on the state of another element (click, hover, scroll, etc). Each div is going to need to listen for a click event, and then run a method to animate the corresponding div. You'll need javascript for this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById

But jQuery will probably get you there faster...
http://api.jquery.com/click/